# Do I need to test for OLS assumptions(autocorrelation and normality) in cross sectional data with 2 time variant control variables?

Tags: econometrics, autocorrelation, stata, cross-section, macroeconomics

My dataset consists of 950k unique loan observations over the period of 4 months. The institution is international, so it has some observations from different countries (not panel data). I am studying the relationship between interest rates and a unique independent variable X. However, I want to control for macroeconomic variables such as unemployment rate(monthly data) in each country and bond yield(monthly data).

My loan data is cross sectional; however, the addition of these 2 macroeconomic variables may change the nature of data. I used OLS regression with robust errors to account for heteroskedasticity in errors. Do I have to test for autocorrelation and normality? Is it valid? I have read that autocorrelation is not valid in cross sectional data due to an absence of time component. But the addition of these control variables is confusing.

1. Is my data now a time series-cross section data?
2. Would it be acceptable to use an average of 4 months for these macroeconomic variables to remove time varying component? The variation across months aren't large.
3. What test should I use for autocorrelation?
4. If there is autocorrelation, should I use cluster option to remove it?

Comment: What would you do if the tests return small p-values? What about large p-values?

Comment: @Dave Before I run the test, I would actually like to know if the data is considered timeseries-cross section or not? Most of the autocorrelation tests tutorials are for time series data only.  How should I test for autocorrelation for my data in stata? Will the command "estat dwatson" suffice?

Comment: I don’t know Stata, but software-specific questions are off-topic on Cross Validated, anyway. However, there is a tea statistical matter: once you find a way to perform a test, how will the result influence what you do subsequently?

Comment: @Dave, I am running an OLS regression, and I want to make sure the assumptions are not violated. If there is indeed autocorrelation, I need to correct the errors.

Comment: And if you get $p>0.05?$

Comment: @Dave That is one of the questions I am trying to clarify in this post. Can I use cluster errors to fix it?